# The product of three consecutive natural numbers is divisible by $6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Please give me feedback for my answer to this question.

> Prove or ﬁnd a counterexample: The product of any three consecutive
>   natural numbers is divisible by $6$

*My answer:* True. Suppose $n$ is a natural number, such that the $3$ consecutive natural numbers is $n, n+1, n+2$. Then, 
$$\begin{align}\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6} 
&= \frac{1(1+1)(1+2)}{6} \\
&= \frac 66 \\
&= 1\end{align}$$
Thus, $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisble by 6.

Comment: It looks like all you proved is that it holds for $n=1$...

Comment: How about if I hold it for all natural numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You have proved that $1\times2\times3$ is divisible by six, not that the product of any 3 consecutive natural numbers is divisible by $6$.

If a number is divisible by $6$, then it must be divisible by both $2$ and $3$. Your product is $$n(n+1)(n+2)$$ so you could try showing that at least one of $n$, $n+1$ or $n+2$ is a multiple of 3, and at least one is even.

Comment: How about this answer? Please give me feedback.

Comment: My answer: True since if we let 1,2,3 be the 3 consecutive natural number then 1*2*3=6 which 6 is divisble by 6, thus the product of any three consecutive natural number is divisble by 6.

Comment: You have to prove it for all $n$. You can't just show that 1*2*3 is divisible by 6 because how does that tell you that 2*3*4 is divisible by 6, Or 25*26*27?

Comment: Following your logic, you could prove that every square number is equal to 1. n^2=1^2=1, so any number to the power of 2 is 1!